# Geckofx Elements

Tags: c#, geckofx

So i have a table with some td's and a's in webbrowser from .net IE i can do to get element from elTB element

```
            HtmlElementCollection elTB = wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TABLE");
            HtmlElementCollection elc = elTB[2].GetElementsByTagName("TD");
```

But if i try on geckofx, it's always giving me error can anyone help ? (i'm new on geckofx and c#)

```
            GeckoElementCollection tables = wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TABLE");
            GeckoElementCollection TD = tables[2].GetElementsByTagName("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
      Gecko.Collections.IDomHtmlCollection<GeckoElement> foo = item.GetElementsByTagName("table");
      GeckoHtmlElement bar = foo[0] as GeckoHtmlElement;
      GeckoElementCollection TD = bar.GetElementsByTagName("a");
```

Most days I wonder if computers are semi-retarded or if it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks for the answer i already found the solution :P but yeah its like yours

```
            GeckoElement elDIVa = wb1.Document.GetElementById("element id");
            Gecko.Collections.IDomHtmlCollection<GeckoElement> elA = elDIVa.GetElementsByTagName("A");
            foreach (GeckoElement el in elA)
            { etc etc }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue come from upper-case, IE using HTML tags in uppercase, GeckoFX use it in Lowercase, so you should change it to:

```
var tables = wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
var TD = tables[2].GetElementsByTagName("a");
```

I sure it will work.